# Style number in div based on the number's value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a number of rows in a table like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="lang_body_2">Upper Management</td>
    <td class="lang_body_2">3.00%</td>
    <td class="lang_body_2">3.40%</td>
    <td class="lang_body_2 index_num">88</td>
</tr>
```

What I'd like to do is style that last cell (the one with "88") based on the value of that cell. That is, if the number (in this case 88) is greater than 50, then change the color of the value (again, 88) to something.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(".index_num").val() == 88) {
        $( this ).css( "color", "red" )
    }
});
```

I'm going to have a bunch of logical statements eventually to define the colors, but I wanted to just get it working on one first before trying a bunch of other things. For example, if the value in the cell is greater than 100 then XYZ, if it's greater than 50 && less than 100, then ZYX (and so on). For now, I'd be happy with just one cell being correct.

Additionally, if I have a number of cells with this same class (.index_num) will they each be able to have a color defined or will it only change to one color based on the cell the script finds first? Obviously, I'd need the first thing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: get the .index_num and add a new css class with addClass(), with the desired color, or change it with .css()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `val()` method is used for form elements like `input`, `textarea` and `select`. What you want to use instead is `text()`, which you'd possibly then want to convert to a number (which I've done below using the Unary Plus (`+`) operator) - this would allow you to use `>` and `<` to check if the value is between a certain range, however there's no need for that if you're only comparing against one value:

```
if (+$(".index_num").text() == 88)
```

Furthermore, `this` will not relate to your `.index_num` element in a simple `if` statement. Assuming you only have one `.index_num` element, you can instead use:

```
if (+$(".index_num").text() == 88) {
    $(".index_num").css( "color", "red" )
}
```

---

```
$(".index_num").each(function() {
    if (+$(this).text() == 88) {
        $(this).css( "color", "red" )
    }
});
```

Comment: Never seen the Unary Plus used like that, nice tip.

Comment: This won't work for me (I don't think) mainly because I have a bunch of divs with the class .index_num. When I try to do an if/elseif, it doesn't work because it simply checks the first value and stops, so the divs won't all change.

Comment: @jonmrich in that case you'll need to use jQuery's `each()` method to loop through each of your `.index_num` elements and apply the style using `this` through that. See: http://api.jquery.com/each/. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Perfect! the each() method worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".index_num").each(function(){
        if (  $( this ).text() == "88" )
            $( this ).css( "color", "red" )
    })
});
```

note "88" with quotes or use

```
if ( parseInt( $(this).val(),10 ) == 88 )
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alemarch/cr1v8mLa/

Answer (score 1):

jquery .each() will help you loop through all your elements with a specific class. I tried something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".index_num").each(function() {
        var score = $(this).text();
        if (score < 50)
        {
            $(this).css("color", "red");    
        }
        else if (score >= 50 && score < 100)
        {
            $(this).css("color", "orange");    
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).css("color", "green");    
        }
    });
});
```

See [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drawhsnq/)

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the last bit I was having trouble with.